# Why do ext2 inodes only have 12 direct blocks?

Tags: filesystems, history, inode, ext2

I'm currently writing a hobby file-system for fun. I was wondering if anyone knows why or where I could get information on the design philosophy of ext2.

Specifically, I was wondering why each inode has only 12 direct blocks? Why not 13, or 100?

Comment: In order to fit a `struct ext2_inode` in 128 bytes?

Comment: Oh, right... that's a pretty good proposition, I guess you could get rid of some reserved fields but fitting it into 128 bytes makes a lot of sense.

Comment: As for close votes: this question explicitly asks for documentation. U&L is probably the best place to put this question (maybe with the exception of retrocomputing SE).

Comment: To add to what @peterph said, that Close reason was created specifically for non-canon learning resources such as tutorials, how-tos, etc. as opposed to official documentation.  In this case, the questioner has not explicitly asked for official documentation but I would say that it’s *implicit*. While it’s possible that there’s no official reason, meaning answers could be “primarily opinion-based”, that’s a wholly different Close reason.  See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2642/22812 and https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3892/22812

Comment: By the way, Joe, be careful with writing hobby systems for fun: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.os.minix/dlNtH7RRrGA/SwRavCzVE7gJ

Comment: See `https://github.com/zfsonlinux/fstest`.